# Toggle hiding of soft keyboard programatically

Tags: java, android, mobile

We have an application that runs on a *barcode scanner android device (ScanSKU)*. And whenever the user is scanning anything the keyboard will show up as it **"types"** the text they scanned, and will block half of the screen.

Our application is basically a **WebView** and we still need to be able to focus form elements inside of it.

But is there anyway we can build a *toggle to disable the on-screen* keyboard from coming up while they are in the WebView?

I've tried using this:

```
// Check if no view has focus:
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

From: [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

**But with no success.**

*Any suggestions or ideas on how I can go about this?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way how to get focus view, getCurrentFocus method didn't work for me too. Try this solution, you should provide instance of Activity object.

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Context context) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken(), 0);
        ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().clearFocus();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // some error log 
    }
}
```

**Edited:** If you use WebView and still need to be able to focus form elements inside of it. You can set attribute

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

for another views on the screen and WebView will hold focus on it.

Comment: So if I were to call this function from my activity, like in onKeyDown. Would I just call it like this: `hideSoftKeyboard(this);` this being the activity? It seems to not work, as soon as I scan something the keyboard comes back up? Or am I using this wrong?

Comment: Yes, `this` is Activity. Method should close keyboard one time, when you call it, but not blocking keyboard next time. Also, I have another suggestion, i will add it to answer.

Comment: By putting this method into a javascript interface for the web view. And calling this whenever there was a focus change in html, as well as when there was a hardware keyboard input (something was scanned) it kept the keyboard hidden. Thank you very much.